# How to generate an pdf invoice in a NodeJs, Express and JQuery?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have made a program based on the stack NodeJs + Express + MongoDB. It is following salesorders in the process of handling. The program works fine.

Now I like to add an option to take the data of a specific salesorder (MongoDB database) and generate a .pdf invoice. Where to start?

Are there programs/options to generate a sort of dynamic fields?

How to fill a certain pdf with data from a database in NodeJs/Express? Preferably with MongoDB?

Comment: [unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14953896/unknown) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66076605) saying "you can use a pdfKit with nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit"

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available to solve your problem.

**Process**

1. Generate and HTML using dynamic values

How to generate?

You can use template engines like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)/[EJS](https://ejs.co/) etc.
They accept JSON and render the HTML page dynamically

2. Generate PDF

How to generate?

There are many npm modules available which take a screenshot of HTML page and generates image or pdf.

Suggestion: Use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)
alternative: phantomjs, jsonToPdf etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML and store it into a variable. Then there are lots of npm package available to convert HTML to pdf.